# Python3 | Expected type 'union[bytes, bytearray], got 'str' instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, odoo

I have a stable working project with python. It's running on python 2.7. I upgraded it to python 3.x. So, it's not working on Python3.

The logic is writing values to csv file.

Broken code is that:

```
csv = io.BytesIO()

csv.write('fiscalYear\t'
                      'VKN\t'
                      'recordPeriod\t'
                      'enteredBy\t'
                      'entredDate\t'
                      'entryNumber\t'
                      'entryComment\t'
                      'batchID\t'
                      'batchDescription\t'
                      'totalDebit\t'
                      'totalCredit\t'
                      'amountOriginalExchangeRate\t'
                      'amountOriginalExchangeRateSource\t'
                      'amountOriginalExchangeRateComment\n'
            )

return csv.getvalue()
```

My problem is that:

```
Expected type 'union[bytes, bytearray], got 'str' instead
```

Python log error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I need your help!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing a string (Unicode) to a BytesIO object.  You should probably switch your BytesIO to a StringIO.  If you truly want bytes, you can convert your Unicode strings to bytes using their `encode()` method, passing your preferred encoding scheme (e.g. `'utf-8'`).

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, you should pass binary data, not strings. Instead of

```
csv.write(my_text)
```

write

```
csv.write(my_text.encode())
```

to convert it to binary.